# Empty iterator range in vector constructor

Tags: c++, stl

Is it valid to pass empty iterator range in vector constructor?
I.e. would it be undefined behaviour in the following code?

```
std::set<int> empty_set;
std::vector<int> target_vector(empty_set.begin(), empty_set.end());
```

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) explanation, this constructor:

> Constructs the container with the contents of the range [`first`, `last`).

Doest it mean **`first`** must be dereferenceable?

Comment: Nice analogy to mathematics: [0.0; 0.0) is empty as well...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's perfectly legitimate to construct a `std::vector` from an empty range.  If `first==last`, the new vector will have no elements, and `first` will not be dereferenced.

The code you have is well-defined, and does what you expect.

---

Since a pointer can be used as an iterator, this even means that this code is well-defined (and returns zero):

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int const* const p = nullptr;
    std::vector<int> v(p, p);
    return v.size();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such requirement.

What it does it allocated memory of size std::distance(first, last) then copies the containment in loop.

Comment: IIRC it allocates **at least** that size, but possibly more. Generally you don't care about `.capacity()`, though.